# oval undermount lavatory sinks that'd fit 18.25" x 15.25" cutout?

Tags: bathroom, sink

I'd like to replace my 20 year old lavatory sinks but keep the countertop, and am having a tough time finding sinks that fit the latter. Can anyone suggest (mfr model or retailer?) oval undermount lavatory sinks that'd fit 18.25" x 15.25" cutout?

Comment: @Tester101, per 'off-topic' suggestion, I can restate the problem as "what oval undermount lavatory sink would fit 18.25" by 15.25" counter cutout most precisely?" Would that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be perfect, but an Ovalyn by American Standard would work with the countertop hanging over the edge all around. Kohler or Bates and Bates will show an inside sink edge beyond the cutout on two sides.

Comment: Thanks, @Jack. Coincidentally, was just looking at 0497.221 model just now.